# how to store arguments in SQL alchemy backed which are passed to celery task in flask app

Tags: flask, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

i am working on flask app which initiate large no of tasks in background using celery , and i am using Redis as message broker queue and SQL alchemy as celery back-end.

By default, i can see "Results" are stored in back-end in "results" column for celery_taskmeta table , but i would like to store args as well which was passed to task .

And i would like to retrieve them as well in future . Is there any way i can store them in my current back-end.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this parameter in your settings =>

```
result_extended = True
```

*Enables extended task result attributes `(name, args, kwargs, worker, retries, queue, delivery_info)` to be written to backend.*

Check out the link for explanation : https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-extended

Comment: Thank you very much for this , i am still not able to get it working with flask , here is flask configuration i picked up from flask celery docs

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/ and added result_extended = True
in celery constructor , not sure if it correct way to use this setting

Comment: may be your version of celery is different then you can try with `CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED=True` instead of `result_extended=True` .

Comment: Thanks again , Yes i tried this option as well but no luck , also i am using 4.4.6 . But i see this issue was there in 4.3 as per Github repo , but i am not sure it was fixed in which version . can i know which version you have , i can try that . Also as of now ended passing argurment also back to task output along with result , so thats arguments will also get stored in results column.  Here is link for github issue that was reported

Comment: i dint get what you meant by `ended passing argurment also back to task output along with result , so thats arguments will also get stored in results column` .

Comment: i have used `celery version 4.4.2` with `elasticsearch result-backend` . whats your result-backend ?

Comment: My result back end is SQL-Alchemy . Also my main objective is to store argument which was passed to task . So  what i did as workaround. I added arguments as well in task results , so that it will get store in results column as well . I will try with this version to see if that helps

Comment: `sql-alchemy` is as far as my knowledge an `sql-engine` which helps as connection between your `python` n `database` . im guessing your DB is `sqlite` ??

Answer (score 0):

`result_backend=True` does not work when loading config using `app.config_from_object()`.

You have to manually update config using `app.conf.update(result_backend=True)`.